# Cannot deploy in wildfly

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wildfly

I am currently following a tutorial. The project consists of one parent project library-app with 3 modules (library-model, library-resource, library-int-tests). 
The maven build process fails when processing library-int-tests.
Here is the exception thrown.

```
13:54:02,028 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."29b978cf-ba15-4c96-a470-9221d44850d1.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."29b978cf-ba15-4c96-a470-9221d44850d1.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "29b978cf-ba15-4c96-a470-9221d44850d1.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018741: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/content/29b978cf-ba15-4c96-a470-9221d44850d1.war/WEB-INF/lib/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:78) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:65) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:122) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.PaddedManifestStream.read(PaddedManifestStream.java:43) [jboss-vfs-3.2.5.Final.jar:3.2.5.Final]
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:441) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:375) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:409) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:376) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:224) [jboss-vfs-3.2.5.Final.jar:3.2.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:208) [jboss-vfs-3.2.5.Final.jar:3.2.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:76) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 7 more
```

POM.xml file of all modules are below.
**pom.xml file of library-app (parent project)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Our library-model src and test jars are below -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.library</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.library</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Our library-model src and test jars are abve -->

    <!-- Our library-resource src and test jars are below -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.library</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-resource</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.library</groupId>
                <artifactId>library-resource</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>

    <!-- Our library-resource src and test jars are abve -->


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-RC.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>library-model</module>
        <module>library-resource</module>
        <module>library-int-tests</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**pom.xml file of library-int-test**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>library-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>library-int-tests</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <version.arquillian_core>1.1.5.Final</version.arquillian_core>
        <version.arquillian.wildfly>8.1.0.Final</version.arquillian.wildfly>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-resource</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-resource</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>skip-int-tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <testExcludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                                    </testExcludes>
                                </configuration>

                                <goals>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>integrationTests-wildfly</id>
            <properties>
                <jboss.home>target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final</jboss.home>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <testIncludes>
                                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                                    </testIncludes>
                                </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IntTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                    <version>${version.arquillian.wildfly}</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>

                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${jboss.home}/standalone/configuration</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>standalone-full.xml</include>
                                            </includes>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>


                </plugins>
            </build>

            <dependencyManagement>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.0-beta-1</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.arquillian_core}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>


            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.arquillian.wildfly}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

**pom.xml file of library-model**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>library-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- used for testing phase only for runtime we will use postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- This hibernate-validator dependency is commented because of validationException. 
            So, below 4.3.2 validation was brought <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> <version>5.1.3.Final</version> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**and finally pom.xml file of library-resource**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>library-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>library-resource</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-model</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Our library-model src and test jars are abve -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am using wildfly 8.1. The error displays something about mockito. I don't understand it. Please help me fix this issue.

Edit: The error and warn log is huge. I wanted to host complete output to pastebin but could not do it because of the size limit. I've hosted some part of the output here http://pastebin.com/S2cSaPBt

Comment: exact error output is helpful

Comment: I have hosted the error at http://pastebin.com/S2cSaPBt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a corrupt `mockito-core-1.9.5.jar` library. You might want to try deleting the JAR from your local repository and rebuilding your application.